# What is a simple example of dependent jointly continuous random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

Most examples of dependent random variables I’ve seen are not jointly continuous.  And most examples of jointly continuous random variables I’ve seen are independent.

So my question is, what is a simple example of dependent random variables which are jointly continuous?  I’ve seen some complicated examples, but I just want some simple examples to build my intuition.

Comment: Take a Gaussian random vector with an appropriate covariance matrix (having non-zero off-diagonal elements).

Comment: @d.k.o. I don’t know what Gaussian random vector and covariance matrix are.

Comment: Consider $(X,Y)$ to be distributed uniformly on the unit ball. Then $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.

Comment: See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution